# Prevent Qt garbage collect QML element

Tags: qt, qml

In my application I have a normal QML tree with several child nodes below the root element. The application calls for some of the sub trees being visible sometimes and others at other times. One approach I have tried is to setParentItem to null for the sub tree I want hidden (to avoid fireing visibleChange events), saving ptr reference for future connection with root element. Problem I have is that Qt's garbage collector then kicks in and frees all nodes in the sub tree.

Can this be avoided somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects without parents and references to them as candidates for collection. On top of that, QMLs garbage collection is [actually broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792876/qml-garbage-collection-deletes-objects-still-in-use). You can disable QML garbage collection altogether for an object by overriding ownership to C++ as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677960/gc-crashes-qml-application/40679374#40679374).

There might be more ways to solve this depending on your actual usage scenarios, for example a [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, toggling the visible flag fires onVisibleChange events which I don't want. Will check if I can disable tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @Johan - you can try setting opacity to 0 to hide and enabled to false to disable input.

Comment: That's my current approach, and it works fine. But seems so much cleaner to remove the whole tree (and faster than recursively set opacity) . I don't think the other solution you proposed will work for me as it requires too much re-write, it's a huge codebase, but it is a neat solution and I'll have that in mind for future applications